# Is there a tactic for solving such trivial goals (lean theorem proving)?

Tags: lean

I'm a beginner and I'm stuck with the following:

```
import tactic.linarith
import tactic.suggest

noncomputable theory
open_locale classical

lemma two_ne_four_mul_any (n:ℕ) : 2 ≠ 2 * 2 * n := begin
  cases n,
  linarith,
  rw mul_assoc,
  ???
end
```

The state is now:

```
n : ℕ
⊢ 2 ≠ 2 * (2 * n.succ)
```

and it seams so trivial, that I thought there must be a tactic for solving it. But linarith, ring, simp, trivial don't work.

So, did I miss some important import?

I also tried to solve this using existing lemmas. In a first step I wanted to reach:

```
n : ℕ
⊢ 1 ≠ 2 * n.succ
```

in the hope that some higher level tactic would now see that it is true. However, I don't know how to do some operation on both sides of an equation. Shouldn't it be somehow possible to divide both sides by 2?

My plan was to proceed by changing the rhs to 2*(n+1) and 2n+2 and maybe the goal to

```
⊢ 0 ≠ 2 * n + 1
```

in the hope of finding applicable lemmas in the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`linarith` knows linear arithmetic, and this is a linear arithmetic goal, but it is obscured by the use of `nat.succ`. If you rewrite it away then `linarith` will work.

```
example (n : ℕ): 2 ≠ 2 * (2 * n.succ) :=
by rw nat.succ_eq_add_one; linarith
```

Comment: These primitive inbuilt tactics like `cases` and `induction` always return cases which are based upon the primitive constructors used to construct the type. Sometimes I would love them to return things like `n+1` and of course this can be done with a more high-powered approach, but most people learn about cases and induction first so this is a common issue.

Comment: Mario, thank you. I will ask another question regarding transformations applied to both sides of an equation.